# Does it matter which view constraints are added to?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I find it convenient to collect all constraints for a whole view hierarchy and adding them all to the local root view. Is this discouraged and/or a bad idea versus adding constraints to the appropriate views?

Below is a simplification of a common pattern I use. The views are often more complicated with multiple stored constraints that needs updating as views are added or removed.

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    UIView *content = ...;
    UIView *panel = ...;
    UILabel *label = ...;
    [self.view addSubview:content];
    [content addSubview:panel];
    [panel addSubview:label];

    NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray new];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[content]|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(content)]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[panel]|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(panel)]];
    [constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[label]|"
                                                                             options:0
                                                                             metrics:nil
                                                                               views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label)]];

    [self.view addConstraints:constraints]
    self.storedConstraints = constraints;

    [super updateViewConstraints];
}

- (void)invalidateConstraints
{
    [self.view removeConstraints:self.storedConstraints];
    [self.view needsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: Some clues at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176446/does-it-matter-which-superview-i-add-constraints-to

Comment: This is fine, so long as the constraints pertain to the subviews of that root view.